# Regex match fix string in hostname

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have hostname like following

`www-foo-1001-1-1.example.com`

I am writing script to which should deploy application which has following string match `1001-<any digit>-<any digit>`

Example: script should match following hostname.

```
www-foo-1001-1-49
www-foo-1001-4-37
www-foo-1001-2-12
www-foo-1001-8-4
```

Ignore this pattern in hostname.

```
www-foo-1001-1-2-49
www-foo-1001-1-1-49
www-foo-1001-1
www-foo-1001
```

## it has to match this pattern `1001-N-N` and ignore anything else.

More details i want to do `if then..` and return `exit` status code with `$?` to throw error who are not matching standard hostname.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes you are correct, i am writing script with will take `hostname` as an argument and validate host before start installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) are enabled within `[[ ... ]]`; so you can do

```
hosts=( www-foo-1001-1-49 www-foo-1001-4-37 www-foo-1001-2-12 www-foo-1001-8-4 www-foo-1001-1-2-49 www-foo-1001-1-1-49 www-foo-1001-1 www-foo-1001 )
pattern='*-1001-+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])'
for h in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    if [[ $h == $pattern ]]; then
        echo "OK: $h"
    else
        echo "no: $h"
    fi
done
```

```
OK: www-foo-1001-1-49
OK: www-foo-1001-4-37
OK: www-foo-1001-2-12
OK: www-foo-1001-8-4
no: www-foo-1001-1-2-49
no: www-foo-1001-1-1-49
no: www-foo-1001-1
no: www-foo-1001
```

My pattern starts with `*-1001-` where I'm assuming that you don't want to match `11001` or `21001` etc.

The `==` operator in `[[ ... ]]` is a pattern matching operator.

The right-hand operand is the pattern variable, but **unquoted**. That allows interpretation of the variable's value as a *pattern* not a *string*.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash:

```
$ touch www-foo-1001  www-foo-1001-1  www-foo-1001-1-1-49  www-foo-1001-1-2-49  www-foo-1001-1-49  www-foo-1001-2-12  www-foo-1001-4-37  www-foo-1001-8-4
$ for f in *
do
  [[ $f =~ 1001-[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && printf 'Yes: %s\n' "$f"
done
Yes: www-foo-1001-1-49
Yes: www-foo-1001-2-12
Yes: www-foo-1001-4-37
Yes: www-foo-1001-8-4
```

This uses bash's regular expression conditional operator to test the argument against:

- contains `1001-`
- followed by some number of digits
- followed by a `-`
- followed by some number of digits
- followed by nothing else: `$`

Answer (score 0):

```
kapu@ppc:$ ls
www-foo-1001        www-foo-1001-1-1-49 www-foo-1001-1-49   www-foo-1001-4-37
www-foo-1001-1      www-foo-1001-1-2-49 www-foo-1001-2-12   www-foo-1001-8-4
kapu@ppc:$ ls | awk '/www-foo-1001-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/{print}'
www-foo-1001-1-49
www-foo-1001-2-12
www-foo-1001-4-37
www-foo-1001-8-4
```